# How to remove the xsi:nil="true" from Perl SOAP::Lite service call?

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, soaplite

Here's the code using [`SOAP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite)

```
my $lookup = SOAP::Lite->service('http://hostname.com/path/SpringVerifierWebServicePort?wsdl')
    -> proxy("$theURL") ;
$response = $lookup->verifySpring();
```

When it executes it produces this request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<verifySpring xmlns="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com" xsi:nil="true" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to remove the xsi:nil="true" on the  tag?

Comment: Hrm, I think I'm right in saying that munging XML with an XML parser would be a bad idea, because SOAP isn't suppose to be done that way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070553/soapdatabuilder-remove-xsinil-true-when-no-value-provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Seems as if it’s a limitation of the SOAP:Lite library (but is easily modifiable).
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=931103